# end selection best practice

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, software

I'm designing a piece of windows software that allows a user to select items on a "canvas" (ex. will be coming up in a jiffy), and after selection somehow confirm the selection.

[image: the tactical view component]

**Context:**
This is a system that allows users to select different players and make a group out of them, these groups are later can be used for statistic purposes. Because not every click on the screen is for selection I added the "New Group" button on the left.
The flow so far:
1. click on "New Group"
2. soccer match is paused allowing for easier selection
3. user selects x number of players (the blue dots with a white ring)
4. user *somehow* confirms selection

Now I have several reservations and **my problem is as follows:**
I don't want to draw too much information on the screen since it may be much more cluttered than what we see in the image. I don't know where players will be when user selects them and I don't want to obscure any player by a "confirm" box.

For even more reference here is the image after several groups have been created and overlay information has been laid over them:

[image: second phase]

Thank you all, I hope I made myself clear enough for you to help me.

Comment: Welcome to stack UX. It's difficult to find your exact question within the text, you could make an edit to make it more clear on the exact question by highlighting the exact question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the button upon click with two buttons showing "Confirm" and "Cancel". The game is paused, the user can select her players and when she is happy with it confirm or cancel the group.

Right now I can not see how you would cancel a grouping action when you started it (other than deleting the group afterwards).

[image: Button to dual button]

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer confirms the other answers and adds the "cancel" option. You really helped me out!

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the 'New Group' button has two states? One state to begin creating a new group and then once the user finishes selecting, the user clicks again to confirm?

The button label could change from 'New Group' to 'Confirm Selection'.

[Example of Dual state buttons](http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/dual-state-buttons)

[image]

Doing it this way means that you do not need to add another button elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Do you allow the user to name the group they have created? If so, the flow could be something like:

1. Click "New Group".
2. Select player(s).
3. Enter name of group and click "Save Group".

As Rob E mentions, you could have the "New Group" button transform (in my example above, into a "Group Name" field ***and*** a "Save Group" button). I actually think you should transform the "New Group" button in some way, otherwise users might assume they are able to create new groups while creating the initial group, which could lead to issues like unsaved groups.